# TypeScript's type inference

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Given these types below, I am not sure why the inferred type of `executor.get()` is different depending on how I invoke `console.log`.

I've included a [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQGUIIOZQDwAqANKgIIB8qA3sKqkgPZgDOArgLZQAUUANlJ0gAuVAQCUIgG4MQAEwDcwAL7BgcVmCQQQTVAAcoUANaFyXZNqYie-QRBHjUAXkrS5EjFlyESBSjToYKAhWGDBqWjp6JjZOGwEoYVExCKioix0weLsxRTSVOiVFFWAkXgRmZlQAUQAPKCRWCAYYU1TUGA08Ci5mLygARhFMHHxiMnIPOoamlu7yPI6u0hIAITM+0aHPUZ8Jkk3cACZh-u61yZFpxubW9cXOrIA6F8OoZlPdhDAATxJvn7kADaAF0pvUbnMAf5IoFgqFwhAABYgZiLAqoSK4CBcDwEdpwkJhVBgVi8XioCqidHKVSMFgQVBQCGzGDOElQADuNRZtzwpPYACNYGZcqpmTNbk9HlxIgZjNlEoyXNEWAx+E9eAxsIrIGIxMAxE9sbj5EA) to the TypeScript playground for your convenience.

```
interface Stage<T, R> {
  consume(element: T): void;
}

function peek<T>(action: (element: T) => void): Stage<T, T> {
  return {
    consume(element: T) {
      action(element);
    }
  };
}

class Executor<T> {
  run<A>(stage1: Stage<T, A>): Executor<A>;
  run<A, B>(stage1: Stage<T, A>, stage2: Stage<A, B>): Executor<B>;
  run(...stages: Stage<any, any>[]): Executor<any> {
    return this;
  }

  get(): T {
    return null as T;
  }
}
```

If I do `peek(element => console.log(element))`, then the inferred return type of `get()` is `number` which is correct.

```
const executor = new Executor<number>();

executor.run(
  peek(element => console.log(element))
).get();
```

But if I do `peek(console.log)` like below, then the inferred return type of `get()` is `any` which I don't understand why. I think because the signature of `console.log` is `console.log(...data: any[]): void`, so when I just pass a reference to `console.log` like below, TypeScript infers that the type of `element` is `any`, but I want `number`, what should I do to make TypeScript infer the correct type?

```
const executor = new Executor<number>();

executor.run(
  peek(console.log)
).get();
```

Answer (score 2):

`console.log` has the following type `log(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;`. As such `peek` when called upon `console.log` will infer that `T` is of type `any` (which is the type of the first argument of console.log).
To fix this, you need to manually tell peek that you will be expecting a number:

```
const executor = new Executor<number>();

executor.run(
  peek<number>(console.log)
).get();
```